# How to use ocamlc option -dprofile and -dtimings?

Tags: ocaml

I know I can use some ocamlc options such as -dparsetree to see the AST generated by the parser.

I can see ocamlc has options `-dprofile` and `-dtiming`. The ocamlc -h tells me option `-dprofile` has four columns: time alloc top-heap absolute-top-heap. I tried to use it like this:

```
ocamlc -c test.ml -dprofile time
```

However ocamlc shows me the -h infomation, so that can't be right.

Can you tell me how to use the options `-dprofile` and `-`-`-`-dtimings` or show me some examples? There are few examples in ocaml's doc and on the internet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about these options. I suspect they are undocumented internal options for developers. This may mean it's for you, actually. It seems you are a developer to be.

Anyway, these commands produced some output for me:

```
$ ocamlc -dprofile -c m.ml
0.004s 1.28MB ------ - m.ml
  0.002s 0.85MB ------ - typing
  ------ 0.03MB ------ - transl
  0.001s 0.38MB ------ - other
0.013s 0.33MB 3.75MB - other

$ ocamlc -dtimings -c m.ml
0.004s m.ml
  0.003s typing
  0.001s other
0.007s other
```

I don't see why you have the argument `time`. But that's probably the problem. Both `-dprofile` and `-dtimings` seem to work when specified alone. If you specify both, the one specified last takes precedence.